# Error in mediactrl_am.cpp while building wxwidgets 3.0.3 with llvm 5.0.0 target x86_64-w64-windows-gnu

Tags: wxwidgets

I'v recently compiled **wxWidgets 3.0.3** with mingw-w64 7.2.0, but due some problems with exception handling now I'm trying recompile them with **llvm 5.0.0** (using **x86_64-w64-windows-gnu** target, standard library from **mingw-w64 7.2.0, 64 bit, seh, posix threads**) which has not those problems.

I have not find instructions how to build current stable version (3.0.3) of wxWidgets with Clang on Windows. So I'm trying a command like

```
mingw32-make.exe -f makefile.gcc MONOLITHIC=1 SHARED=1 BUILD=debug CXXFLAGS=" -fexceptions -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fnon-call-exceptions -std=gnu++11 -pthread " LDFLAGS=" -fexceptions -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fnon_call_exceptions -pthread "  CC="clang -target x86_64-w64-windows-gnu" CXX="clang++ -target x86_64-w64-windows-gnu" COMPILER_PREFIX="clang"
```

in ..\build\msw subdirectory to build one of the possible configurations.

(With mingw-w64 I used also `LDFLAGS=" -Wl,--allow-multiple-definition "`, possible here will be problems with multiple symbols too. I've also [pathched](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/commit/06458cb89fb8449f377b0b782404b9a9cbe3ae2d#diff-9cf4eef4822377649a928c11237e38f6) source code as I had problems with wxPrintf)

The first error I have:

```
../../src/msw/mediactrl_am.cpp:2234:10: error: case value evaluates to
      4294966687, which cannot be narrowed to type 'DISPID' (aka 'long')
      [-Wc++11-narrowing]
    case 0xfffffd9f: // readystatechange in IActiveMovie2 and IMediaPlayer
         ^
1 error generated.
```

My account on wxWidgets forum not activated yet, so I ask here.

**May be somebody knows correct way how to repair this issue?**

Comment: you are not building with MinGW, right? Find the proper compiler executable and try to build the libraries as appropriate. However, I think you are on your own here - I don't think cross-compiling with clang for Windows is supported. I may be wrong though.

Comment: @Igor I use clang version for windows, not cross-compiler. The clang version for windows is only compiler. The libc++ is not ported yet, so clang uses other standard libraries, linkers and so on. In my case from mingw-w64 toolchain. Old versions of wxwidgets can be compiled by clang with some patches. I can't use mingw or mingw-w64 compiler in my project.

Comment: like I said - you're on your own since I don't think too many people tried to compile wx with clang on Windows. Try posting to wx-dev ML or wx-users ML to get better exposure. BTW, did you try MSVC? Or you are stuck with MinGW toolchain? And finally - if MinGW had problems I think switching just compiler won't resolve them. Do you?.

Comment: @Igor MSVC is not free for commercial project. Clang has all features I need (except one)

Comment: @Igor The clang is only one free compiler I know, where floating point exceptions are always catching in up level function as expected with -fnon-call-exception option (when they throwing from signal handler or windows unhandled exception handler). In mingw those exceptions can be catched or a program will be terminated, and this depends on code position and optimization options. As my code needs exceptions always catched, I can't use mingw. I don't need underfined behavior al all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious fix for this particular problem seems to be to replace this value with `-609`.

However I need to warn you that, to the best of my knowledge, nobody has compiled wxMSW using clang so far (even though clang can be used for compiling wxGTK and wxOSX, of course), so you may well run into other, less trivial, problems later. I'd also recommend trying to compile the latest git master instead of 3.0.3 as any non-trivial changes that might be required for clang build are unlikely to be done in the stable 3.0 branch.

Comment: Oops, indeed, sorry, I completely forgot about this one (but then it was 7 years ago, too...).